# Asciidoc. Highlight an xml or any other source code in a table cell

Tags: xml, documentation, asciidoc, asciidoctor

Well, actually the problem is in the question title. I want to render some xml located in some table. W/o table the clause '[source, xml]' works perfectly. But in a table cell everything is ignored and rendered 'as-is' as a raw text. Are there any tricks/workarounds to make asciidoc highlight xml in a table cell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an open issue with the PDF Rendering in Asciidoctor:

https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/6